# newbie c++ casting a list iterator to a POD type

Tags: c++, casting

I have

```
class ListIterator 
{
    public:
        ListIterator(std::list<double>& ls) :lst(ls) {lit = lst.begin();}
        double *next(void);
    private:
        std::list<double> lst;
        std::list<double>::iterator lit;
};
```

this

```
double *ListIterator::next(void)
{
    return((double *)&lit++);
}
```

generates an error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]

I don't see why &lit++ is taking an address of a temporary since it should take the & of lit and then increment it, never-mind that lit++ should not be a temporary either.

this

```
double *ListIterator::next(void)
{
    double *res = &lit;
    lit++;
    return res;
}
```

generates an error: cannot convert ‘std::list::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator*}’ to ‘double*’ in initialization

while this

```
double *ListIterator::next(void)
{
    return((double *)&lit);
}
```

compiles w/o problems

can someone help me understand why?

TIA,
Yannis

ps. I am using gcc 4.8 with -std=c++11

Comment: lit is an iterator - something like a pointer but not the same as one. &lit gives you a pointer to the iterator, what you want is the value of the iterator with *lit. 
With a c-type cast (double*) you can cast whatever to whatever, means in your code (the 3rd one) you casted a iterator* to double*, wich will give you weird results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double *ListIterator::next(void)
{
    double *res = &(*lit);
    lit++;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: yes, this did the trick, thank you :), I still don't understand why the return(double *)lit compiles though, if you care to answer, it should be double *res = &(*lit)

Comment: I guess that '((double *)&lit)' interpret what is pointed by 'lit' as a double

Answer (score 0):

Postfix `operator ++` returns a copy which in the context you are using it is a temporary variable which will not exist once you leave `next`. Although, I think you really mean to take the address of the contents of the iterator not the iterator itself.

Comment: you mean that since I am using it in the return, the operator++(int) will generate a temporary, but if I use it in the member function body like in the 2nd example it will increment the private members (lit) value??!! Why?

Comment: In the second case you are not taking the address of a temporary, which you know it succeeds because you are telling the compiler to cast it to a `double *` which it will happily let you do, although you should see a warning. When you cast you are saying I know what I am doing if you don't things will usually break in bad ways.

Comment: true, butwhy I got a lot of times errors like "error: cannot convert ‘std::list<double>::iterator* {aka std::_List_iterator<double>*}’ to ‘double*’ in initialization" then as for example in double *res = &lit?

Comment: thanks Safik, ignore my last post, I forgot to cast in the case i mentioned